# Read text file in R and convert it to a character object

Tags: r, types

I'm reading a text file like this in R 2.10.0.

```
248585_at   250887_at   245638_s_at AFFX-BioC-5_at
248585_at   250887_at   264488_s_at 245638_s_at AFFX-BioC-5_at  AFFX-BioC-3_at  AFFX-BioDn-5_at
248585_at   250887_at
```

Using the command
    `clusters<-read.delim("test",sep="\t",fill=TRUE,header=FALSE)`

Now, I must pass every row in this file to a `BioConductor` function that takes only character vectors as input.

My problem is that using `as.character` on this "clusters" object turns everything into numeric strings.

```
> clusters[1,]
         V1        V2          V3             V4 V5 V6 V7
1 248585_at 250887_at 245638_s_at AFFX-BioC-5_at
```

But

```
> as.character(clusters[1,])
[1] "1" "1" "2" "3" "1" "1" "1"
```

Is there any way to keep the original names and put them into a character vector?

Maybe it helps: my "clusters" object given by the "read.delim" file belongs to the "list" type.

Thanks a lot :-)

Federico

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default character columns are converted to factors. You can avoid this by setting `as.is=TRUE` argument:

```
clusters <- read.delim("test", sep="\t", fill=TRUE, header=FALSE, as.is=TRUE)
```

If you only pass arguments from text file to character vector you could do something like:

```
x <- readLines("test")
xx <- strsplit(x,split="\t")
xx[[1]] # xx is a list
# [1] "248585_at"      "250887_at"      "245638_s_at"    "AFFX-BioC-5_at"
```

Answer (score 1):

I never would have expected that to happen, but trying a small test case produces the same results you're giving.

Since the result of `df[1,]` is itself a `data.frame`, one fix I thought to try was to use `unlist` -- seems to work:

```
> df <- data.frame(a=LETTERS[1:10], b=LETTERS[11:20], c=LETTERS[5:14])
> df[1,]
  a b c
1 A K E
> as.character(df[1,])
[1] "1" "1" "1"
> as.character(unlist(df[2,]))
[1] "B" "L" "F"
```

I think turning the `data.frame` into a `matrix` first would also get around this:

```
m <- as.matrix(df)
> as.character(m[2,])
[1] "B" "L" "F"
```

To avoid issues with factors in your `data.frame` you might want to set `stringsAsFactors=TRUE` when reading in your data from the text file, eg:

```
clusters <- read.delim("test", sep="\t", fill=TRUE, header=FALSE,
                       stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

And, after all that, the unexpected behavior seems to come from the fact that the original affy probes in your data.frame are treated as factors. So, doing the `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` thing will side-step the fanfare:

```
df <- data.frame(a=LETTERS[1:10], b=LETTERS[11:20],
                 c=LETTERS[5:14], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> as.character(df[1,])
[1] "A" "K" "E"
```