# Converting a list into a character object in R

Tags: r

I would like to convert a list as follows:

```
    list(structure(c(16L, 17L, 71L, 87L, 113L, 120L, 127L, 128L, 
      144L, 177L, 207L, 213L), .Names = c("246653_at", "246897_at", 
      "251347_at", "252988_at", "255528_at", "256535_at", "257203_at", 
      "257582_at", "258807_at", "261509_at", "265050_at", "265672_at")))
```

into a character object:

```
         c("246653_at", "246897_at", "251347_at", "252988_at", "255528_at", 
         "256535_at", "257203_at", "257582_at", "258807_at", "261509_at", 
         "265050_at", "265672_at")
```

I tried using

```
    as.character(fin[1])
```

which gives me

```
   [1] "c(16, 17, 71, 87, 113, 120, 127, 128, 144, 177, 207, 213)"
```

I referred to [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867139/read-text-file-in-r-and-convert-it-to-a-character-object) but couldn't solve it.

Comment: Have you tried using `unlist`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your object is `x`:

```
> names(unlist(x))
 [1] "246653_at" "246897_at" "251347_at" "252988_at" "255528_at" "256535_at"
 [7] "257203_at" "257582_at" "258807_at" "261509_at" "265050_at" "265672_at"
```

Answer (score 3):

Or just...

```
names(fin[[1]])
 [1] "246653_at" "246897_at" "251347_at" "252988_at" "255528_at" "256535_at"
 [7] "257203_at" "257582_at" "258807_at" "261509_at" "265050_at" "265672_at"
```